# redirecting the output of a command to a file in python, how to do it

Tags: python, output, redirect

I'm trying to output the value of a command to a file. I've tried:

```
threaddump() >> /dir/newdir/newfile.log
```

and it's not working.

So, how can I redirect the output of a command to a file in a directory? The version of python is 2.3.4.

Comment: Have you tried to write to a file using regular file operations?

Comment: You can do this easily using a >& command $mypymodule.py >& log.file

Answer (score 1):

There is a misconception in your approach. Python is not a shell, but a simple interpreter. A shell allows starting a program and it can always[1] supply some context data to the started program, like environment variables, a current working directory but also its standard IO streams (stdin, stdout, stderr) for redirection to a file. Since any Python function runs in the same process as the caller, it can use the same global objects though, which includes the streams.

This leaves you with a few ways to solve your problem:

1. Temporarily redirect sys.stdout to a file. This is especially useful if changing the called code isn't a good option, otherwise I'd rather not do this since it effects the whole process.
2. Return the data from the function and print it to a file at the caller's site.
3. Pass a file to the function, which the function prints to.

[1] The only exception I know of is MS Windows CE, which doesn't have environment vars, a working directory or a way to pass standard IO streams.

Comment: any answers ??? i have tried out a few options, but the >& doesnt work well as there is a CRON job thats running and the output when the error occured is being overwritten with the latest run , which was successfull.

Comment: Which of the three options is not an answer? And which "few options" did you try? Also, the ">" redirection is not in Python but in the calling shell, see my explanation concerning the difference.